# How do you create line segments between two points?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this bit of code that plots out the points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from matplotlib import pyplot

all_data = [[1,10],[2,10],[3,10],[4,10],[5,10],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5]]
x = []
y = []
for i in xrange(len(all_data)):
    x.append(all_data[i][0])
    y.append(all_data[i][1])
plot.scatter(x,y)

pyplot.show()
```

[image: what it shows]

but I want all the possible lines that could be made that looks something like this:

[image]

I've tried matplotlib path, but it doesn't work well for me.

Comment: Not sure about the matplotlib question, but you can save some lines of code by using `x, y = zip(*all_data)` instead of your loop (or `x, y = map(list, zip(*all_data))` if you need lists instead of tuples).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools 

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
all_data = [[1,10],[2,10],[3,10],[4,10],[5,10],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5]]
plt.plot(
    *zip(*itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(all_data, 2))),
    color = 'brown', marker = 'o')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: is there anyway you can catalog how many points each line intersects?

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting question, completely independent of plotting. Please post it as a new question so people smarter than I will chime in.

Comment: A brute force solution would be to write a function which returns `True` if given 3 collinear points, `False` otherwise. Then inside the `for pair in itertools.combinations(...)` loop you simply test collinearity for every point in `set(all_data)-set(pair)` with the points in `pair`...

Comment: You saved my day with `*zip`.

Answer (score 28):

This can be optimized but it works:

```
for point in all_data:
    for point2 in all_data:
        pyplot.plot([point[0], point2[0]], [point[1], point2[1]])
```

[image]

Comment: How can it be optimized? Is the pyplot.plot() call insanely expensive? Is it possible for me to just call it once??

Answer (score 5):

One other way could be to use matplotlib patches

```
import matplotlib
import pylab as pl
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.path import Path

verts = [(x1,y1), (x2,y2)]
codes = [Path.MOVETO,Path.LINETO]
path = Path(verts, codes)
ax.add_patch(patches.PathPatch(path, color='green', lw=0.5))
```

Answer (score 4):

using all combinations?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from matplotlib import pyplot

all_data = [[1,10],[2,10],[3,10],[4,10],[5,10],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5]]
x = []
y = []
for i in combinations(all_data,2):
    x.extend(i[0])
    y.extend(i[1])

plot.plot(x,y)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: combinations isn't working, it says                                                    george@P632144:~/Desktop$ python line_cluster_3.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "line_cluster_3.py", line 8, in <module>
    for i in combinations(all_data,2):
NameError: name 'combinations' is not defined

Comment: @George sorry you should import it: from itertools import combinations see unutbu answer