# connecting all numpy array plot points to each other using plt.plot() from matplotlib

Tags: numpy, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a numpy array with xy co-ordinates for points. I have plotted each of these points and want a line connecting each point to every other point (a complete graph). The array is a 2x50 structure so I have transposed it and used a view to let me iterate through the rows. However, I am getting an 'index out of bounds' error with the following:

```
     plt.plot(*zip(*v.T)) #to plot all the points
     viewVX = (v[0]).T
     viewVY = (v[1]).T
     for i in range(0, 49):
        xPoints = viewVX[i], viewVX[i+1]
        print("xPoints is", xPoints)
        yPoints = viewVY[i+2], viewVY[i+3]
        print("yPoints is", yPoints)
        xy = xPoints, yPoints
        plt.plot(*zip(*xy), ls ='-')
```

I was hoping that the indexing would 'wrap-around' so that for the ypoints, it'd start with  y0, y1 etc. Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm a little lost. First, `plt.plot(*zip(*v.T))` seems to do the same thing as `plt.plot(v[0], v[1])`. Second, your question makes it sound like you want a line between every pair of points (maybe a complete graph?) but that's not what your code does. Could you be a little more clear about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes Bago, I'm trying to draw a complete graph and getting my code to do that is proving a problem for me. Thanks for the simpler plt.plot(v[0], v[1]) syntax. I'm new to numpy and matplotlab. I'll edit my question to make explicit the complete graph.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create line segments between two points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834483/how-do-you-create-line-segments-between-two-points)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools

v=np.random.random((2,50))
plt.plot(
    *zip(*itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(v.T,2))),
    marker='o', markerfacecolor='red')
plt.show()
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that there are fewer calls to `plt.plot`. This should be significantly faster than methods that make O(N**2) calls to `plt.plot`.

Note also that you do not need to plot the points separately. Instead, you can use the `marker='o'` parameter.

---

Explanation: I think the easiest way to understand this code is to see how it operates on a simple `v`:

```
In [4]: import numpy as np
In [5]: import itertools
In [7]: v=np.arange(8).reshape(2,4)
In [8]: v
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

[itertools.combinations(...,2)](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) generates all possible pairs of points:

```
In [10]: list(itertools.combinations(v.T,2))
Out[10]: 
[(array([0, 4]), array([1, 5])),
 (array([0, 4]), array([2, 6])),
 (array([0, 4]), array([3, 7])),
 (array([1, 5]), array([2, 6])),
 (array([1, 5]), array([3, 7])),
 (array([2, 6]), array([3, 7]))]
```

Now we use [itertools.chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to convert this list of pairs of points into a (flattened) list of points:

```
In [11]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(v.T,2)))
Out[11]: 
[array([0, 4]),
 array([1, 5]),
 array([0, 4]),
 array([2, 6]),
 array([0, 4]),
 array([3, 7]),
 array([1, 5]),
 array([2, 6]),
 array([1, 5]),
 array([3, 7]),
 array([2, 6]),
 array([3, 7])]
```

If we plot these points one after another, connected by lines, we get our complete graph. The only problem is that `plt.plot(x,y)` expects `x` to be a sequence of `x`-values, and `y` to be a sequence of `y`-values.

We can use `zip` to convert the list of points into a list of x-values and  y-values:

```
In [12]: zip(*itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(v.T,2)))
Out[12]: [(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3), (4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 7, 5, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7)]
```

The use of the splat operator (`*`) in `zip` and `plt.plot` is [explained here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/).

Thus we've managed to massage the data into the right form to be fed to `plt.plot`.

Comment: that is fantastic - thanks! I haven't used itertools before so some of the syntax in the plt.plot call is unfamiliar to me. Is this similar to  nditer?

Answer (score 2):

With a 2 by 50 array,

```
 for i in range(0, 49):
    xPoints = viewVX[i], viewVX[i+1]
    print("xPoints is", xPoints)
    yPoints = viewVY[i+2], viewVY[i+3]
```

would get out of bounds for `i = 47` and `i = 48` since you use `i+2` and `i+3` as indices into `viewVY`.

Comment: Is there a way of iterating through array elements from different starting points so the iteration wraps back round to the starting element?

Comment: Modular indexing, `(i + 2(3)) % 50` would wrap it back to 0 when it reaches 50.

Comment: thanks that solved my indexing problem. But I just need to sort out which points to send for a complete graph.

Comment: Happy to help. I'm afraid I can't help you with the plotting, though,not my domain.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with, but I hope someone comes up with something better.

```
def plot_complete(v):
     for x1, y1 in v.T:
          for x2, y2, in v.T:
             plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 'b')
     plt.plot(v[0], v[1], 'sr')
```

The `'b'` makes the lines blue, and `'sr'` marks the points with red squares.

Comment: Bago, thanks - this is basically what I got it down to too. I prefer your cleaner syntax. I am starting to get used to the idea of labelling columns with just the 'for x1, y1 in v.T' syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Have figured it out. Basically used simplified syntax provided by @Bago for plotting and considered @Daniel's indexing tip. Just have to iterate through each xy set of points and construct a new set of xx' yy' set of points to use to send to plt.plot():

```
        viewVX = (v[0]).T #this is if your matrix is 2x100 ie row [0] is x and row[1] is y
        viewVY = (v[1]).T
        for i in range(0, v.shape[1]): #v.shape[1] gives the number of columns
           for j in range(0, v.shape[1]):
              xPoints = viewVX[j], viewVX[i]
              yPoints = viewVY[j], viewVY[i]
              xy = [xPoints, yPoints]         #tuple/array of xx, yy point
              #print("xy points are", xy)
              plt.plot(xy[0],xy[1], ls ='-')
```